# I'm trying to insert a node in the root of a tree, but it doesn't insert anything (In C)

Tags: c, pointers, null, binary-tree

I'm trying to construct a tree from a input string written in PostOrder notation. So, I read the string and pass the last character (Before '\0') as the parameter of the function "convertToTreeFromPost" but when this function finishes doing its work, at the moment of writing in Preorder the tree i have just created, the root of my tree is pointing to null. How can I solve this?
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//======================================================================================
//Creación del nodo a través de estructuras
typedef struct nodo
{
  char data;
  struct nodo *left;
  struct nodo *right;
} nodeType, *node;


//======================================================================================
//creamos la estructura de tipo árbol BINARIO
typedef struct arbol
{
  node root;
} treeType, *tree;


//Creamos el nodo con left and right apuntando a nada
node createNode( char data_ );

//Creamos el arbol
tree createTree();


//Escriba el árbol creado en modo inOrder. DEBE TENER POR PARÁMETRO LA RAIZ DEL ARBOL EN LA 1RA SUMMON
void writeInOrder( node node_ );

//Escriba el árbol creado en modo PreOrder. DEBE TENER POR PARÁMETRO LA RAIZ DEL ARBOL EN LA 1RA SUMMON
void writePreOrder( node node_ );


//Escriba el árbol creado en modo PostOrder. DEBE TENER POR PARÁMETRO LA RAIZ DEL ARBOL EN LA 1RA SUMMON
void writePostOrder( node node_ );


//Convierte la cadena de caracteres en modo PostFijo a un árbol binario. La primera vez que se invoque la función, el parámetro DEBE OBLIGATORIAMENTE ser el nodo raíz del árbol y el último elemento de la cadena que sea un caracter legible
char* convertToTreeFromPost( node node_, char* elemento );

int main(void) {

  tree newTree = createTree();

  char input[1000];
  
  printf("Ingrese el arbol en notacion PostFijo\n");

  fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin );

  int inputSize = strlen(input);

  
  char* lastElement = &input[inputSize - 2];

  //printf("\nLa raiz del arbol apunta a: %p\n", newTree -> root );
  
  //Le restamos 1, para evitar imprimir el '\0' que simboliza el fin del string y le restamos otro 1, porque las posiciones en el arreglo empiezan desde 0 y NO desde 1.
  char* pierdase = convertToTreeFromPost( newTree -> root, lastElement );

  printf("\nEl arbol en PreOrden es: \n");

  //printf("\nLa raiz del arbol apunta a: %p\n", newTree -> root );
  
  writePreOrder( newTree -> root );
  
  return 0;
}


node createNode( char data_ )
{
  node newNode = (node) malloc( sizeof( nodeType ) );
  newNode -> data = data_;
  newNode -> left = NULL;
  newNode -> right = NULL;

  return newNode;
}

tree createTree()
{
  tree newTree = (tree) malloc( sizeof( treeType ) );
  newTree -> root = NULL;

  return newTree;
}

void writeInOrder( node node_ )
{
  if( node_ != NULL )
  {
    writeInOrder( node_ -> left );
    printf("%c", node_ -> data );
    writeInOrder( node_ -> right );
  }
  else
  {
    printf("#");
  }
}


void writePreOrder( node node_ )
{
  if( node_ != NULL )
  {
    printf("%c", node_ -> data );
    writePreOrder( node_ -> left );
    writePreOrder( node_ -> right );
  }
  else
  {
    printf("#");
  }
}


void writePostOrder( node node_ )
{
  if( node_ != NULL )
  {
    writePostOrder( node_ -> left );
    writePostOrder( node_ -> right );
    printf("%c", node_ -> data );
  }
  else
  {
    printf("#");
  }
}

char* convertToTreeFromPost( node node_, char* elemento )
{
  if( (*elemento) != '#' )
  {
    //printf("\nNode 1 es: %p\n", node_ );
    node_ = createNode( (*elemento) );
    //printf("\nNode 2 es: %p\n", node_ );
    elemento = (elemento - 1);
    elemento = convertToTreeFromPost( node_ -> right, elemento );

    if( (*elemento) != '#' )
    {
      elemento = convertToTreeFromPost( node_ -> left, elemento );
      return elemento;
    }
    else if( (*elemento) == '#' )
    {
      elemento = (elemento - 1);
      return elemento;
    }
  }
  else if( (*elemento) == '#' )
  {
    
    elemento = (elemento - 1);
    
    if( (*elemento) != '#' )
    {
      return elemento;
    }
    else if( (*elemento) == '#' )
    {
      return elemento;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Look at `char* pierdase = convertToTreeFromPost( newTree -> root, lastElement );`.  Code passes in `newTree -> root` and `lastElement` yet never sets `newTree -> root` to anything.    Re-design  `convertToTreeFromPost()` to return the node created.

Comment: can you please provide some example input with the expected output ?